# How to convert C++ sort function to Swift?

Tags: c++, swift

I am converted a C++ coding to Swift Coding. But, I am not able to understand exactly this function `sort(v.begin(), v.end());`. But, I've written what I've understand from that.

The problem is swift code gives different output than regarding C++ code.## Heading ##

**C++**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

ll solve(ll N,ll K,vector<ll > &token){

    ll ans=0;

    vector< pair<ll, int> > v;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)

        v.push_back( make_pair(token[i], N - i));

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(int i = 0;  i < N; i++){
        if( K >= v[i].second * v[i].first){
            K -=  v[i].second * v[i].first;
            ans += v[i].second;
        }
        else{
            ans += K / v[i].first;
            K = 0;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main(){
    ll N = 57;
    ll K = 877914575;

    static const int arr[] = {436426,979445,648772,690081,933447,190629,703497,47202,407775,894325,963982,804784,968417,302156,631932,735902,895728,78537,723857,330739,286918,329211,539679,238506,63340,686568,361868,660016,287940,296263,224593,601449,836991,890310,823355,177068,11431,8580,291757,449218,374934,594328,163676,829355,996221,899080,195922,531545,748511,34067,575467,338674,284691,206504,999835,262034,344965};

    vector<ll> token (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
    cout<<solve(N,K,token);
}
```

**Swift Code (I tried to convert):**

```
import Foundation

typealias ll = Int64

func solve(_ N:ll, K:ll, token:inout [ll])->ll{

    var ans:ll = 0
    var K = K
    var v = [(first:ll,second:ll)]()

    for i in 0..<N{

        v.append((token[Int(i)],N-i))
    }
    v = v.sorted(by: { (element1, element2) -> Bool in

        return element1.first > element2.first
    })

    for i in 0..<N{

        if(K >= ll(v[Int(i)].second) * v[Int(i)].first){

            K -= ll(v[Int(i)].second) * v[Int(i)].first
            ans += ll(v[Int(i)].second)
        }else{
            ans += K/v[Int(i)].first
            K = 0
        }
    }
    return ans
}

func main(){

    let N:ll = 57;
    let K:ll = 877914575;
    var token:[ll] = [436426,979445,648772,690081,933447,190629,703497,47202,407775,894325,963982,804784,968417,302156,631932,735902,895728,78537,723857,330739,286918,329211,539679,238506,63340,686568,361868,660016,287940,296263,224593,601449,836991,890310,823355,177068,11431,8580,291757,449218,374934,594328,163676,829355,996221,899080,195922,531545,748511,34067,575467,338674,284691,206504,999835,262034,344965]
    print(solve(N, K: K, token: &token))

}

main()
```

Regarding above codes C++ gives output to `1637` and Swift gives `1438`. But without `Sorting` those are gives same number `1612`

I thought I am doing wrong in sorting the values of `v`. But, I am not sure below Swift code is equivalent to C++ sorting.

**Sorting in above code:**

**C++:**

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

**Swift**

```
v = v.sorted(by: { (element1, element2) -> Bool in

    return element1.first > element2.first
})
```

Why those programs gives different value? How can I solve that?

**Update:**

**Inputs:**

```
let N:ll = 57;
let K:ll = 877914575;
var token:[ll] = [436426,979445,648772,690081,933447,190629,703497,47202,407775,894325,963982,804784,968417,302156,631932,735902,895728,78537,723857,330739,286918,329211,539679,238506,63340,686568,361868,660016,287940,296263,224593,601449,836991,890310,823355,177068,11431,8580,291757,449218,374934,594328,163676,829355,996221,899080,195922,531545,748511,34067,575467,338674,284691,206504,999835,262034,344965]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1637
```

Comment: *"Why those programs gives different value?"* – Without providing the input data, the expected and the actual input (ideally a [mcve]) this question is useless for future readers.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-vector-of-pairs-in-c-set-1-sort-by-first-and-second/) article explains how the default implementation of `sort` works for a vector of pairs in C++, it simply sorts the vector in ascending order based on the first element.

Your Swift code does the opposite, sort in descending order. Simply change `return element1.first > element2.first` to `return element1.first < element2.first` and you should be good.

Btw you shouldn't just convert code word-by-word between languages. Convert the **algorithm**, not the C++ code.

Comment: I spent two hours to find out, But I can't.. Thanks for your help